# Dumping ASIO channels to STDIO

Tags: asio

Awhile back, I found a tool for connecting to ASIO applications and dumping the raw audio data to STDIO so it could be captured or converted with a tool like FFmpeg.  However, I don't know the name of it.  Do you happen to know the name of this utility, or is there another way to export live ASIO raw samples?

Comment: Was that in Windows, or something like WineASIO?

Comment: It was in Windows.  I didn't even know ASIO worked in Wine, but that's good to know that it does!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I am genuinely curious what potential application/niche (or problem you are hoping to resolve) this sort of workflow serves. Since ASIO is requires dedicated "ownwership" of the hardware, do you want to have multiple computers/VMs running independently and then {magic} to combine them on a separate machine through STDIO?

Comment: @horatio Two projects... the first is for internet radio encoding.  I've written some software that handles streaming internet radio, but I am not familiar with the ASIO API.  I thought that before I invest a bunch of time in hacking through it, I could find something that already does the ASIO heavy lifting.  Edcast ASIO meets the general need here, but is quite buggy as it was never finished.  The second project is a browser extension for connecting web apps to ASIO.  Obviously there would be latency issues here, but it could still work for applications where latency isn't a large concern.